# A question about the topological properties of tetrahedrons

Tags: geometry

Let T be a solid tetrahedron with 4 pairwise distinct non-coplanar vertices which is a subset of 3 dimensional Euclidean space E(3). If p is any interior point of T and Q(p) is any plane which is a subset of E(3) and contains p, does Q(p) always strictly separate two of the vertices of T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. All planes which contain at least three vertices are faces of the tetrahedron, hence any interior point can be coplanar with only two vertices. So there are at least two vertices not contained in $Q(p)$.
2. A plane which has all tetrahedron points strictly on one of its sides passes by the tetrahedron without intersection. A plane which contains one vertex while having the other three on one side touches at a vertex, and a plane which contains two with the other two on one side touches at an edge. So if you assume that all non-contained vertices are unseparated, then you end up in one of these cases, where plane and tetrahedron have no inner points in common.

Comment: Many thanks. It seems clear that your proof will generalize to non-degenerate simplexes in any finite dimensional Euclidean space. The  three dimensional case allows one to prove some interesting facts about map projections onto the surface of a celestial globe.